# Messaging system. Question about database design

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm designing a messaging system that will have to support a huge amount of messages and users.

I was thinking about two solutions.

```
Usertable -> id, username ....
Messagetable -> id, from_id, to_id, message ...
```

Or:

```
Usertable -> id, username ....
Messagetable -> id, message ...
HasMessagetable -> id, from_id, to_id...
```

I'm wondering what is the best approach to this and why.

Also, are there good publications (free or not) about large databases design and best practices?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't use a database as a message queue.  Please use a message queue as a message queue.  There are lots of robust, reliable message queue solutions that work straight out of the box without you having to build anything.

Comment: The questions you ask are rather basic, so I think you might be better off using a ready-to-use messaging system like ActiveMQ.

Comment: I need to store them in a database anyway for future reference, it's not a chat, it's something more similar to a mailing system.. if I'm missing something can you provide a link with an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same not too long ago and started out with approach 1. But then users were supposed to be able to send messages to multiple users. Suddenly approach 1 saved each message n times if n recipients were addressed. So if this is ever a possibility, I think 2 is better.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the less joins you have to do, the better your queries will perform.  Therefore, the first option will probably be a better choice since you are going to have a very large database.

Basically, you are going to need to ignore some database normalization techniques in order to gain the performance you need.  However, try not to limit yourself either.  For example, if you have messages that go to multiple people, you are going to need to either choose option two or figure out a different way to handle this.

As for resources for large database design, here is one for Microsoft SQL Server but a lot of the things it discusses will apply:

http://sqlcat.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your second schema is more normalized.  Both are acceptable.  Properly normalized database design is cleaner, but for perfomance reasons many DBA resort to [denormalisation](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/04/denormalization-patterns.html). I would use the second schema, until you hit performance issues this would be the better approach in my very humble opinion.

Do note that normalising to that extent is often considered overkill by many, as others have posted. I do it that way from habit and old (now outdated) DB theory courses I learned 12 years ago.

Happy-coding